# Inductive vs projective limit of sequence of split surjections

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Let
$$
A_1\twoheadrightarrow
A_2\twoheadrightarrow
A_3\twoheadrightarrow
A_4\twoheadrightarrow
\cdots
$$
be an inductive sequence of abelian groups, the connecting homomorphisms of which are surjective and **split**, that is, we have embeddings $A_{n+1}\rightarrowtail A_n$ such that the diagram
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A_n & \twoheadrightarrow & A_{n+1}\\
\uparrow &  & \uparrow\\
A_n & \leftarrowtail & A_{n+1}
\end{array}
commutes for every $n$. Here the vertical arrows denote identity homomorphisms. This means that $A_{n+1}$ is a direct summand of $A_n$.

Let $\varinjlim A_n$ denote the inductive limit of the system
$$
A_1\twoheadrightarrow
A_2\twoheadrightarrow
A_3\twoheadrightarrow
A_4\twoheadrightarrow
\cdots
$$
and let $\varprojlim A_n$ denote the projective limit of the system
$$
A_1\leftarrowtail
A_2\leftarrowtail
A_3\leftarrowtail
A_4\leftarrowtail
\cdots.
$$
We get an induced map
$$
\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n.
$$
**Question:** Is the map $\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n$ necessarily an isomorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample: we take $A_i = \mathbb{Z}^{\times \mathbb{N}}$, with all the homomorphisms $A_i \to A_{i+1}$ being the left shift operator and the splittings $A_{i+1} \to A_i$ the right shift operator. Then $\varinjlim A_\bullet \ne 0$, because the sequence $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ cannot be annihilated after finitely many steps, but $\varprojlim A_\bullet = 0$ because we can rewrite the inverse chain
$$A_1 \leftarrowtail A_2 \leftarrowtail A_3 \leftarrowtail \cdots$$
as a decreasing chain of subspaces of sequences that have the first non-zero entry at position $i$, and the only sequence that is in all of these subspaces is the sequence $(0, 0, 0, \ldots)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask a follow-up question: if we have $\varinjlim A_\bullet=0$, then can we conclude that $\varprojlim A_\bullet=0$?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of any reason why that should be the case, nor any counterexample.

Comment: I posted a [follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/254822) for this weaker version of the question. Do you think it is possible to construct of *countable* counterexample for *this* question (question 254649)?

Comment: I don't see why not. Instead of taking the whole of $\mathbb{Z}^{\times \mathbb{N}}$, we could take the submodule generated by $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ (which is countable) and the sequence $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$; in other words, this is the space of eventually-constant sequences.

Comment: Correct link to follow up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254822/inductive-vs-projective-limit-of-sequence-of-split-surjections-ii

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much.