# Inductive vs projective limit of sequence of split surjections II

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

This question is a follow-up of [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254649) I asked.

Let
$$
A_1\twoheadrightarrow
A_2\twoheadrightarrow
A_3\twoheadrightarrow
A_4\twoheadrightarrow
\cdots
$$
be an inductive sequence of abelian groups, the connecting homomorphisms of which are surjective and **split**, that is, we have embeddings $A_{n+1}\rightarrowtail A_n$ such that the diagram
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A_n & \twoheadrightarrow & A_{n+1}\\
\uparrow &  & \uparrow\\
A_n & \leftarrowtail & A_{n+1}
\end{array}
commutes for every $n$. Here the vertical arrows denote identity homomorphisms. This means that $A_{n+1}$ is a direct summand of $A_n$.

Let $\varinjlim A_n$ denote the inductive limit of the system
$$
A_1\twoheadrightarrow
A_2\twoheadrightarrow
A_3\twoheadrightarrow
A_4\twoheadrightarrow
\cdots
$$
and let $\varprojlim A_n$ denote the projective limit of the system
$$
A_1\leftarrowtail
A_2\leftarrowtail
A_3\leftarrowtail
A_4\leftarrowtail
\cdots.
$$
We get an induced map
$$
\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n.
$$
As [Zhen Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5191/zhen-lin) has shown in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254702/367) to my earlier question, this map need not be surjective. Here is a weaker question:

**Question:**
If we have $\varinjlim A_n=0$, then can we conclude that $\varprojlim A_n=0$?

This would, of course, follow if the map $\varprojlim A_n\to\varinjlim A_n$ was always injective. Is there any reason to expect this?

Comment: I re-asked this question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116060/inductive-vs-projective-limit-of-sequence-of-split-surjections